# Маршруты для маршрутизации PHP

Tags: php, router, route

Добрый день, сообщество! Хочу написать для себя хороший роутер, посмотрел разные варианты: с маршрутами, без маршрутов, управление только через URI  и тд и тп. Имею небольшой опыт программирования на PHP, поэтому, почитав тут, там, решил написать сюда. Решить этот вопрос, так сказать, в живых ответах. Суть: хочу, чтобы у меня маршруты были в таком виде

```
return array(
 "index"=>array("controller"=>"index", "method"=>"index","args"=>array("number"=>"2", "type"=>"family")),
 "notes/([-_a-z0-9]+)"=>array("controller"=>"index", "method"=>"index", "args"=>array("param"=>"2", "mouse"=>"grey")),
 "note/([/d])"=>array("controller"=>"index", "method"=>"index", "args"=>array("number"=>"2", "type"=>"family")),
);
```

Иными словами, хочу брать строку из URL, и, сопоставляя ее с маршрутами получить контроллер, метод, аргументы. (Как всегда короче).

По принципу этого:

```
return array(
    'about' => 'page/show/about',
    'page/([-_a-z0-9]+)' => 'page/show/$1',
    'users/([-_a-z0-9]+)' => 'users/show/$1',
);
```

Теперь вопросы:

1. Мне не совсем понятен принцип сопоставления ключа, в котором используется регулярное выражение со значением. А именно это:

   ```
   'page/([-_a-z0-9]+)' => 'page/show/$1'
   ```

   Правильно ли я понял, что регулярное выражение ([-_a-z0-9]+) и $1 являются одним и тем же? Как это читается? Мол,$1 присваивается значение регулярного выражение в ключе массива?
2. Не думаете ли Вы, что столь подробное разбиение маршрута на контроллер-метод-аргументы в самом массиве маршрутов, в какой-то мере затруднит работу в будущем? Стоит ли так делать? Может лучше как обычно получать строку, и уже потом в самой функции ее разбивать и дальше с ней работать?

Да, смотрел разные реализации маршрутизаторов, в фреймворках и просто решения. Не хотелось бы лишних манипуляций, которые обычно предлагают в фреймворках. Насчет велосипедов: я не собираюсь изобретать что-то новое, просто хочу сделать мне удобное решение, чтобы работало и чтобы я полностью понимал что там делается. Возможно, изъезженная тема, но, думаю, все имеют какие-то предпочтения в поиске какого-то решения. Может Ваше решение и будет точкой этого вопроса.

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: В дополнение отмечу, что само ничего не дополняется, как я мог по своей неопытности думать. Нужно использовать preg_replace();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да, вы правы. Конструкция `([-_a-z0-9]+)`  является регуляркой. А $1 присваивается результат этой регулярки.
2. В вашей схеме я вижу одну проблему. Нету разделения на методы(GET,POST). Иногда полезно в зависимости от метода вызывать определенную функцию, удобно для построений API. А так мне бы надоело писать так подробно. Тут идет дело в удобстве.

Мне больше привычнее такой способ.

```
$router->get('/blog/(\/[A-Za-z0-9\.,_-]+)', function($post_id){
    return (new MainСontroller())->getIndex($post_id);
});
```

Тут удобно, то что у IDE есть подсказки.